# Load con SwalAlert

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

cuando estoy cargando la página quiero que me aparezca la alerta de que se esta cargando la información y así el usuario debe esperar a que la página este cargada.  Yo tengo un código que me esta levantando la alerta, pero le esta dando la opción al usuario de interactuar antes que levante la alerta.  Mi código es el siguiente

```
<script>
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        swal.close();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var swalInit = swal.mixin({
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-light'
        });

        swalInit({
            title: 'Cargando',
            text: 'Información en proceso',
        })
    });
</script>
```

La idea es que cuando llame a la página me levante inmediatamente la alerta y una vez cargada desaparezca la alerta, por el momento cuando termina de cargar la página desaparece la alerta y esta bien, pero mi problema se genera en que demora en aparecer y permite que el usuario pueda llamar antes a otra acción.

Ayuda

Comment: Demora en aparecer porque lo estas poniendo en un `$(document).ready`(La funcion se ejecutara cuando el documento este listo), solo quitalo de ahi y ya

Answer (score 0):

**SWAL no tiene esa capacidad.**

Para que tu puedas lanzar una tarea antes que la información se cargue puedes meter la función en el `<head>` esto de una forma sencilla lanzará cualquier script puesto ahí mira

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.15.5/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log( 'Inició' );
        const swal =  Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer');
    </script>
</head>
```

El problema con ello es que SWAL se sirve de que el `<body>` para anclarse y si este aún no está del todo listo, tronará. Te recomiendo hagas algo más rústico con CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> console.log( 'Inició' ); </script>
        <style>
            .loader {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('https://lkp.dispendik.surabaya.go.id/assets/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $( () => {
            $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
            console.log('terminó');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Y cómo recomendación `$(document).ready()` es un método que está deprecado de hace tiempo, deja de usarlo, en su lugar pasale una función anónima

```
$( () => {
  ... Aquí todo tu código Jquery/Javascript
})
```